# swift **willSelectRowAtIndexPath** enable and disable options

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have Options such as:

1. None
2. Had once
3. Every time
4. SomeTime

now if none is selected i want other options to be disabled and disable none if any of the options or all are selected.
I have done

```
func tableView (tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

    // first 3 rows in any section should not be selectable
    if indexPath.row <= 1 {
        return nil
    }

    return indexPath
}
```

This lets me to select only others except none. How can i achieve my requirements. Any ideas will be really appericiated.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your requirement? can you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a global variable to keep track of the current selected row and modify the code in your willSelectRowAtIndexPath method as follows :

```
var selectedRow = -1 //Global Variable

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
{
    if(indexPath.row>0 && selectedRow == 0) //When "None" option row is selected & user tries to select any other row.
    {
        return nil
    }

    else if(indexPath.row == 0 && selectedRow > 0) //When any row other than "None" is selected and user tries to select "None" option row
    {
        return nil
    }
        else //When no row is selected or rows other than "None" are selected and user tries to select any row other than "None" row.
        {
            selectedRow = indexPath.row
            return indexPath
        }
}
```

Tested the above code and its working as per your requirements. Do let me know if thats what your were looking for. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.it works. but what happens is when i select none all other options cannot be selected this is what i wanted. but again when i deselect none still other options cannot be selected..

Comment: add a deselect delegate function of tableview and set selectedRow = -1 whenever a row is deselected, the code will work as required by you.